# My JavaScript Custom error message refuses to clear even when the condition turns true

Tags: javascript, if-statement, error-handling

My Custom error message i created to always display when ever a certain condition is true is not being cleared even when the condition turns false.
Help me out pls ...I don't know what else to do!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcnTP.jpg)

Comment: Give us a snippet of the offending code, and we can get started on helping you :)

Comment: Please send a screenshot of the expected output and the code of your problem

Comment: Just set the message to null

Comment: You have to remove the error message when your condition pass.

Comment: Also, you may want to use `if (content.length != 6){ }` instead

Answer (score 0):

innerHtml is for text, I guess you are using textbox on your errormsg ? if it so, instead of innerHtml try using .value.
Please provide jsfiddle so we can see the codes clearly.